# Python product frequently bought with

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, combinations

I have retail store transactional data and want to see what categories are bought together. The data is in the below format:

| transaction_no | product_id | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100012 | A |
| 1 | 121111 | A |
| 1 | 121127 | B |
| 1 | 121127 | G |
| 2 | 465222 | N |
| 2 | 121127 | M |
| 3 | 121127 | F |
| 3 | 121127 | G |
| 3 | 121127 | F |
| 4 | 465222 | M |
| 4 | 121127 | N |

**Rules:**

1. The result should be aggregated based on unique transaction numbers.
2. Also, the order shouldn't matter in this case (e.g. A bought with B is the same as B bought with A).
3. If a category is repeated within the same transaction, it should be counted as 1 only (e.g. in transaction_no = 1, category A is counted once)

Expected output:

| bucket | count |
| --- | --- |
| A, B, G | 1 |
| N, M | 2 |
| F, G | 1 |

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) for aggregate `frozenset`, then count values by [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and last create DataFrame with join for strings from frozensets:

```
df1 = (df.groupby('transaction_no')['category']
        .agg(frozenset)
        .value_counts()
        .rename(lambda x: ', '.join(sorted(x)))
        .rename_axis('bucket')
        .reset_index(name='count'))
print (df1)
    bucket  count
0     M, N      2
1     F, G      1
2  A, B, G      1
```

Another idea:

```
df1 = (df.groupby('transaction_no')['category']
        .agg(lambda x: ', '.join(sorted(set((x)))))
        .value_counts()
        .rename_axis('bucket')
        .reset_index(name='count')
        )
print (df1)
    bucket  count
0     M, N      2
1     F, G      1
2  A, B, G      1
```